# Image slider in layout

Tags: zend-framework2

I need to develop image slider that will be in layout but i'm begginer in zf2. Is any method to load image src from database? I know how to set variables in onBootstrap() the only problem is to connect db and retrive data via fetchAll() in my tableGateway.

Comment: Surprisingly someone answered this question, i wouldn't... Follow the link of @Remi Thomas and then come back with real questions.

Answer (score 1):

About your image slider, I think it will be in jquery, bootstrap ? 
so you have just to print result from your database.
for example this : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuilt zf2 module:-

```
https://packagist.org/packages/ledsinclouds/leds-js-slider
```